# MYSQL: number of queries per second from different users/devices

Tags: php, mysql, database, server, web-hosting

For the past few hours I've been searching around and I haven't been able to find an answer. I read somewhere online that a guy received a warning from his shared hosting services regarding a high query per second and the number was around 38 queries per second. I really don't have much background in this field but how could this be possible? I thought a website can handle hundreds of hits at a time? I know it's a SHARED hosting but I'm really shocked.

I'm working on a project and I am expecting 100 users accessing my MYSQL database from different devices. Each user will poll the database every 3 seconds to do a single query and the query takes about 0.001sec at most. Do I have to be concerned about this and see if a shared hosting can handle this load? Even though the users are accessing the database from different devices (IP's)? I keep reading online that it's impossible to answer such questions and it depends on the shared hosting capabilities and so on... Can somebody please tell me if I'm confusing different concepts here? As I said I'm pretty new to such topics.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have no information about the Hardware, but only one point is this. Lets say you want to change every time the same record (only sample) and this record is store on the hard disc on block 1 and the HD has 5000 RPM then you can change block 1 ONLY 83 times per second (5000/60 sec). So the bottleneck are mostly the WRITES (insert,update delete) and one update updates mostly also some indexe and must change more than 1 block. see also what @Xymanek has answered

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I never thought abour HD RPM that way...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a huge deal. MySQL was built to handle massive load in enterprise environments and I don't think 38 queries/sec is enough to create a bottleneck (if there is enough hardware).

As you said, it's a shared hosting. This means that all sites are using same MySQL server. So I guess that the hosting company was concerned about how this site will affect other ones.

Also as a general rule, shared hosting is targeted at either low-popularity sites or static ones. So if your friend has a site that has more visitors than the particular SHARED hosting can handle, he should upgrade to either better shared or a vps.

**EDIT** Also read this question on stackoverlow for better understanding of how many queries should a site do: [How many MySQL queries should I limit myself to on a page? PHP / MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561900/how-many-mysql-queries-should-i-limit-myself-to-on-a-page-php-mysql)

Comment: Thanks. I think vps is a good solution. I'll look more into this.